# Can I save photoshop images as a vector?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector

I do not have Illustrator, but need to send a file to someone as a vector. Can I save my Photoshop image as a vector?

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, RobinS. See [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7944/photoshop-layers-into-svg-paths). And also read [here](http://creativedroplets.com/generate-svg-with-photoshop-cc-beta/): it *could* depend on your version and on the kind of layers to be exported.

Comment: Short answer - No. But possibly some some simple SVGs if you are using CC. There is a previous question about it [here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/17865/how-to-create-vector-graphics-in-photoshop-cs6)

Comment: The short answer is **you can't use Photoshop**. Photoshop does not now, and never has created real vector files. It merely creates raster files with embedded vector data. There **is** a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you used vector elements in Photoshop (like shapes, smart objects, fonts etc.), you can save as eps. Then, send the eps to that someone. He/she can open the eps in Illustrator and enjoy the vectors.

Comment: Photoshop EPS files are **not** vector EPS files. They are raster EPS files with possibly some embedded vector data. See here: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/is-a-photoshop-eps-file-a-vector-format

Comment: Good mention. Yes, I was talking about pure vector elements in ps. If you use raster (in ps or in ai) then it is obvious that you will not have e pure vector eps file.

Answer (score -1):

You may also use [Pixel2Vector - free plugin for Photoshop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCrKLhQyUAk)

*What it does?*
**It converts directly a raster image/shape into vector format.** In Photoshop.

*Where goes the new vector?*
**Above the original layer.**

*How good it is?*
Not as good as image tracing in Illustrator; **depends heavily on the image** (the bigger in size, the more accurate the tracing).

Comment: Did you try this? It just seems to convert a selection to a work path, which Photoshop can do all on its own. And you **won't** get a vector file.

Comment: We use it constantly. Just to make clear: it **converts** the image into vector path, it doesn't save it as such.